# Text to different columns with pandas using delimiters

Tags: python, regex, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a big excel sheet with all the data in the same cell about different people. I have split up the data so that I have delimiters. I used (-) to separate different individuals and (;) to separate the information about those individuals. I want to split the data into different columns using those delimiters, but not every cell contains the same number of people information so I cannot used a fixed number of columns. I need to create a dataframe according to the data that I have.

This is an example of how my data looks like:
[image]

As you can see, in each cell there are different number of people listed. 
I want a final output like this:
[image]

Always the name of the person comes followed by (-) and I only care about the three first data about each individual that corresponds to Name, Title and Email, the rest is redundant .
I tried text to columns in excel and it deleted most of the rows. Also, I tried split by delimiter with regex but I can't do it in multiple columns, since I have to delimit the number of columns.

So, I need a code to iterate through all the rows, split the information by (-) and position the first string after the (-) in the first column, the second string after the (;) in the second column, and the third string after the (;) in the third column, and so on. This have to continue for an unlimited number of times since some cells have one member and other have multiple.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks too. Next time show your code and full error message.

Comment: please share your code that you have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heads-up. If you're attempting to delimit based on "-" note that this character also appears in other places e.g. "Co-Founder". One approach could be to first handle these instances such that "-" only ever appears before a name. As you mention you'd like a pandas DataFrame, an apply statement could be used to format the information of each row:

```
import itertools

import pandas as pd


def format_records(row):
    """Split records to construct DataFrame"""

    # Replace 'Co-Founder' with 'CoFounder'. The '-' will cause the split command to think Founder is someone's name
    row = row[0].replace('Co-Founder', 'CoFounder').replace('Co-founder', 'CoFounder')

    # Split each record (one per person) using '-' as the delimiter
    records = row.split('-')[1:]

    # Split data constituting each record by ';' and return the first three elements
    elements = [r.split(';')[:3] for r in records]

    # Construct new row by joining the first three elements of each record
    new_row = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(elements))

    # Correct for the previous co-founder conversion
    new_row = [r.replace('CoFounder', 'Co-Founder') for r in new_row]

    # Convert to series
    new_series = pd.Series(new_row)

    return new_series


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Read in data
    df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=None)

    # Re-organise data
    new_df = df.apply(format_records, axis=1)

    # Number of times the ['Name', 'Title', 'Email'] sequence should repeat (based on number of columns of new_df)
    repetitions = int(new_df.shape[1] / 3)

    # Add column names
    new_df.columns = ['Name', 'Title', 'Email'] * repetitions
```

Comment: I get the following error:
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 266 elements, new values have 264 elements

Comment: Could there be an extra '-' somewhere that is causing a record to be delimited at an incorrect location? Commenting out: `new_df.columns = ['Name', 'Title', 'Email'] * repetitions` and inspecting the output could help to identify the row where the error occurred.